# Modal button inside table th doesn't work

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-modal

I have created a table with modal button inside the `table` `th` but when it is clicked, only the background turned darker. Here is the table thead code where the modal button is placed.

```
                 <thead class="align-middle text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Special Skills and Hobbies <span type="button"
                                class="float-end text-muted small smodal" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#skill_Modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"
                                    aria-hidden="true"></i></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
```

At the table end tag, I have added a simple script that will trigger the modal to show:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.smodal').click(function () {
                    $('#skill_Modal').modal('show')
                });
            </script>
```

And here is the modal codes I am using.

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="skill_Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="skill_ModalLabel"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="skill_ModalLabel">Update other Information / Membership
                            </h1><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <form action="skillController.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table text-muted table-striped table-bordered small">
                                        <thead class="align-middle text-center">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="col">Special Skills and Hobbies</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="table-group-divider" id="skills_tablebody"></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-bg-primary"
                                    onclick="plusSkill();"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Other
                                    Info</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer"><input type="hidden" name="id"
                                    value="<?=$row['id'];?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-success" name="special_skills_btn">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.